# Request Error: No ad to show at Rewarded (Interstitial) AdMob Ads in SwiftUI with demo AdUnitID but Banners are working

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, admob

i'm trying to integrate Google AdMobs ads into my iOS app.

The app is created with SwiftUI in Xcode 14 and referencing GoogleMobileAds 9.11.0.

I don't have a google AdMobs account yet, so I'm just testing with google's demo AdUnitIDs, and as I do not have an apple developer account yet, I can only run my app in simulator.

Banner Ads are loading well, but when trying to load an interstitial, rewarded or rewarded interstitial ad, I always get: `Request Error: No ad to show`.

Here is the code, I use for loading the rewarded/interstitial ads:

```
    func LoadRewarded(){
        let request = GADRequest()
        
          GADRewardedAd.load(
            withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                request: request, completionHandler: { (ad, error) in
                     if let error = error {
                         print("Rewarded ad failed to load with error: \(error.localizedDescription) ")
                         return
                     }
                     self.rewardedAd = ad
                     self.rewardedAd?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
                }
          )
    }
```

You can find a my full demo app here:
https://github.com/dev-revati/admob9-swiftui-rewarded-interstitial

Why is my app not able to load any rewarded/interstitial ads?

Comment: I tried my test app again two days later and was able to show a rewarded interstitial ad once, but wasn't able to reproduce.